# Android: SQLiteException: no such column when i use subqueries

Tags: android, sqlite

I've stucked with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (

SELECT tab._id t_id, tab.name name, pics.pic1 pic FROM mushrooms tab
JOIN mushrooms_pics pics ON t_id = pics.id WHERE t_id IN 
(SELECT item_id FROM coordinate WHERE type = "mushrooms") UNION

SELECT tab._id t_id, tab.name name, pics.pic1 pic FROM berries tab
JOIN berries_pics pics ON t_id = pics.id WHERE t_id IN
(SELECT item_id   from coordinate WHERE type = "berries") UNION

SELECT tab._id t_id, tab.name name, pics.pic1 pic FROM herbs tab
JOIN herbs_pics pics ON t_id = pics.id WHERE t_id IN 
(SELECT item_id from coordinate WHERE type = "herbs")

) 
LEFT JOIN coordinate c ON t_id = c.item_id WHERE t_id IN 
(SELECT item_id from coordinate)
```

The query works fine in "DB Browser for SQLite", but in my app i get an error, here's the error in LOGCAT:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: herbs (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT name FROM( SELECT tab._id t_id, tab.name name, pics.pic1 pic FROM mushrooms tab JOIN mushrooms_pics pics ON t_id = pics.id WHERE t_id in (SELECT item_id from coordinate WHERE type = mushrooms) UNION SELECT tab._id t_id, tab.name name, pics.pic1 pic FROM berries tab JOIN berries_pics pics ON t_id = pics.id WHERE t_id in (SELECT item_id from coordinate WHERE type = berries) UNION SELECT tab._id t_id, tab.name name, pics.pic1 pic FROM herbs tab JOIN herbs_pics pics ON t_id = pics.id WHERE t_id in (SELECT item_id from coordinate WHERE type = herbs) ) LEFT JOIN coordinate c on t_id = c.item_id WHERE t_id in (SELECT item_id from coordinate)
```

Are there any ideas how can i fix this? 
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, strings use single quotes.
Double quotes are used to escape table or column names.

(SQLite allows both in either context, but this does not help in an ambiguous context.)